# R Programming: replace missing values in column of a data frame

Tags: r, missing-data

I am trying to replace all missing value in a column of a data frame. I found the below code:

```
          df$GROUPE[is.na(df$GROUPE)] <- "OTHER"
```

However, I am receiving a error message:

```
       Warning message:
       In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, is.na(df$GROUPE), value = c(NA, 1L, 2L,  :
       invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Does anybody know how to replace missing values.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your factor to character then run the previous line again:

```
df$GROUPE <- as.character(df$GROUPE)

df$GROUPE[is.na(df$GROUPE)] <- "OTHER"
```

You can refactor the `df$GROUPE` variable after:

```
df$GROUPE=as.factor(df$GROUPE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your `GROUPE` column is a factor and does not have a level called `"OTHER"`.

```
levels(f) <- c(levels(f), "OTHER")
```

should add it.